# Saving Django 400 bad requests for analyzing purposes

Tags: python, django

I have a Django-based API.

Sometimes my customers inform me that some of the their requests return 400 (bad request) even that they're not supposed to.

I thought about a good way to handle and debug that exact problem, by saving the failed-requests, with all of the headers (such as the Access Token) and a timestamp, so when I'll see problematic pattern I'll be able to debug it and find the reason.

My question regarding to my method is - how can I "trigger" a function that will collect the request with all of its headers everytime that I'm returning a response with 400 status?

Comment: Are the 400 responses actually generated by Django itself ?

Comment: I use Django rest framework and the 400 is being generated there for bad requests, but I want it to generally check the status on the returned response and decide if logging is required

Comment: cf my answer then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 400 response is generated by Django, you can use a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/) (beware: the middleware api changed in 1.10, for django <= 1.9 the doc is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/)) and the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) - just make sure your logging is [correctly configured](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/) in your django settings.

If the 400 response happens at a higher level then you'll have to check the relevant doc according to how your project is deployed

Also FYIY `django.core.WSGIHandler` yields a 400 response when a `UnicodeDecodeError` happens while instanciating the `HttpRequest` object - in this case AFAICT the middlewares won't even be invoked. You should already find traces of these occurences in the logger configured for `django.requests` (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/logging/#django-request)